# Access a variable declared in one view controller from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I want to access the searchController variable declared in a tableviewcontroller

```
var searchController:UISearchController? = nil

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()  

       let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SegueTableViewController") as! SegueTableViewController
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable
}
```

in the second view controller, which is also a tableviewcontroller, I want to access the searchController from the first view controller.

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows


        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
            return filteredUsers.count
        }
        return self.usersArray.count

    }
```

Comment: Your app will crashed with this code! Go to the Apple's developers website and download the sample code for UISearchController

Comment: I currently have it this way and it doesn't crash @Mannopson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a global variable by placing the declaration outside your ViewController instead. I don't necessarily like this solution, but at this moment it's the only one I can think of.

Comment: When I place it outside the viewcontroller, I can't access the variable in the viewcontroller.

Comment: I actually wasn't doing it properly and I finally figured out how to do it and your solution worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a common class that you import into both your view controllers and access the variables thru common methods.

Here is a quick super simple example.

```
class centralDB: NSObject {

  private var commonSpace: String

  func returnSpace() -> String {
    return commonSpace
  }

  func setSpace(blah: String) {
    commonSpace = blah
  }
}

centDB = centralDB() // This is a global variable in centralDB

-------

import centralDB

class viewCon1 {
  centDB.setSpace("viewCon1 set this")
}

-----

import centralDB

class viewCon2 {
   centDB.returnSpace()
   print variableInCommon // shoould output ViewCon1
}
```

Edited this since I think the initial code was incorrect. You can get the idea I am sure.